# Rename user's group name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, user-accounts

I just did `usermod -l login-name old-name` to change the username, but the group name is still the old one.

Any way of renaming the group name? I can't find any info to do so.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`groupmod` should work fine. Run it as superuser:

```
# groupmod --help
Usage: groupmod [options] GROUP

Options:
  -g, --gid GID                 change the group ID to GID
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -n, --new-name NEW_GROUP      change the name to NEW_GROUP
  -o, --non-unique              allow to use a duplicate (non-unique) GID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       change the password to this (encrypted)
                                PASSWORD
```

Use it like this:

```
groupmod --new-name NEW_GROUP_NAME OLD_GROUP_NAME
```

Note that this takes effect immediately and you do not need any logout/login.

Comment: run it as a superuser

Comment: Does it require a logout, login to take effect, like adding someone to a group does?

Comment: @Jonathan: No, it takes effect immediately.

Answer (score 17):

To **reNAME** as you asked:
`sudo groupmod -n new-name current-name`

**Note:** If the name already exists but you want to use it anyway:
`sudo groupmod -o -n new-name current-name`

If you are root you don't need to use `sudo`

Comment: To list existing groups. Execute -> groups